# Is deleting two or three consecutive nucleotides and inserting exactly two or three back more common than two or three consecutive SNP?

Tags: dna, cancer, mutations, snp, dna-damage

I am looking at cancer mutations. I found that some of the mutations are e.g.

1. c.1251_1252delGGinsTT
2. c.151_152delGGinsTC
3. c.351_352delCAinsTT

I wonder if these are indeed two consecutive single nucleotide polymorphisms, such that they are indeed:

1. G>T, G>T
2. G>T, G>C
3. C>T, A>T

I would like to know which scenario is more biochemically plausible. I would like to distinguish them because I am looking for grouping them into mutation categories. I am not sure if I should treat these as indels or SNPs.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it is SNPs, though they can be di-nucleotide polymorphism (DNP) or TNP. I saw this on some common oncogenes, e.g. TP53.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification,  I think you'd better include all the information and ask again in bioinformatics stack exchange ( , you will receive immediate feedbacks).

Comment: Please also refer to SNP and indel definitions:  https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Variant_classification, (https://snp.gs.washington.edu/SeattleSeqAnnotation154/HelpIndelAnnotation.jsp)